# Possible reasons for ConditionalRejectingErrorHandlerExecution

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm getting the following error for the *rabbitmq* application.

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandlerExecution of Rabbit message listener failed.
```

We are using spring-amqp 1.6.6 version. I want to know the possible reasons for this exception.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Any** exception thrown by the listener will cause this, as well as anything that will prevent the listener from being called (such as a message conversion exception).

1.6.x is no longer supported; the current 1.x version is 1.7.10.